# What Vancouver car rental companies allow their rental cars to enter the US?

Tags: usa, canada, car-rentals, australian-citizens, vancouver

Which Vancouver car rental companies allow their rental cars to enter the US for a significant period of time (four weeks or longer), assuming the car will be returned to them in Vancouver?  I'm an Australian citizen.

Comment: Are you a Canadian Citizen, an American, or some other? This makes a difference.

Comment: Better question: Which companies do not.

Comment: @CGCampbell Added a note that I'm an Australian.  As such, I don't have much experience with rental cars and international boundaries.  I know some offered cross-boundary rentals but I would have thought there'd be limits?

Comment: I have not noticed any limits in car rental contracts and it's quite common to cross the Canadian-US border with rental cars in either direction ( returning the car in the country of origin). Insurance is usually valid either side. Mexico is a completely different situation. Suggest you shop for a rental, then confirm. Four weeks+ is a relatively long rental and different rules may apply to the insurance.

Comment: Actually most companies make you sign that you will *not* take the car to the US. I regularly rent cars in Canada and almost always told not to take it over the border. It's too bad because it's very close and I could refill the tank for less.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an issue with you taking a car from Vancouver and returning it in the US.

Just did a search on [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com/cars/YVR-a6668/SEA-a7054/2015-06-16/2015-06-30) picking up in Vancouver Airport and dropping off in SeaTac airport and the major rental companies are happy to oblige even though it's getting a bit pricey.